# ArrayList is clearing when new values are inserting in adaper

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view which is showing fruit list. Each item has a buy button.When I click the buy button of an item in the list, the details of that item should pass to the order list page through intent and should be displayed in recycler view.I have used ArrayList for passing the data.Then when I click the continue button it will come back to fruit list page and I want to buy another fruit.But my issue is, when I click the buy button of another item, only that particular item is displayed in the order list.the previous item is missing and the recycler view is showing only one row.(ie, latest data).Can any one please help?

this is the adapter code:

```
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        fruitname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
        rate = (TextView) view.finenter code heredViewById(R.id.rate);
        buy = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.buy);
        mProfilepic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profilepic);

    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View rootView = LayoutInflater.
            from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, false);
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rootView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    return new ViewHolder(rootView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    item = mListItem.get(position);

    final ViewHolder mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) viewHolder;

    mViewHolder.fruitname.setText(item.get_name());

    mViewHolder.rate.setText(item.get_email()+"/kg");

    }
    mViewHolder.buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            item1.set_contact(mListItem.get(position).get_designation());
            item1.set_bank_fee(mListItem.get(position).get_name());
            item1.set_category(mListItem.get(position).get_email());                                     
            dataItem.add(item1);

      Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,OrderListActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("arraylist",dataItem);
      mContext.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mListItem.size();
}
```

note:I have used notifyDataSetChanged.

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.order_list);
    mrecyclerview = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.fruits_recycler);
    mrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new 
    LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

   dataItem = 
   (ArrayList<ListItem>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arraylist");
   mOrderAdapter = new OrderAdapter(OrderListActivity.this,dataItem);
    mrecyclerview.setAdapter(mOrderAdapter);
    mOrderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
} 
}
```

Comment: can you share your complete code for both the classes??

Comment: you can use singleton class which has dataItem list...just simple onClickListener add into dataItem(in singleton) and startactivity..then there you can pass dataItem to adapter..because when you call startActivity it creates new activity every time not the previous activity with ur previous data...so every time it generates new dataItem..so resulting only one row in orderlist..

Comment: share second class also

Comment: i have posted the OrderListActivity.datalist is initialised above oncreate

Comment: Could you check my answer?

Comment: Can I do this using database???

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,OrderListActivity.class);
// edited here
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("arraylist", productList);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

And next Activity .

```
ArrayList<ListItem>) dataItem = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("arraylist");
if (dataItem != null && dataItem.size() > 0) {
    mOrderAdapter = new OrderAdapter(OrderListActivity.this, dataItem);
    mrecyclerview.setAdapter(mOrderAdapter);
    // remove this 
    // mOrderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```